Долгое переключение между фрагментами в нижнем меню
В MainActivity реализовано нижнее меню. Макет состоит из BottomNavigationView и FragmentContainerView. В случае, если фрагмент, соответствующий пункту меню пустой, тот тут все понятно - загрузка идет моментально.
В случае, когда я переключаюсь на наполненный фрагмент, где есть карточки, кнопки, текст и т.д., то ощущается неприятная микрозадержка.
Как оптимизировать процесс загрузки фрагмента? В некоторых приложениях замечал, что часть макета подгружается уже после того, как он появился на экране
UPD:
Navbar настраивается следующим образом в MainActivity:
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main) as NavHostFragment

        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)


приведите пожалуйста пример кода который используется для показа фрагмента, переключение нижнего меню

@Andrew обновил

а я попрошу код фрагмента, который тормозит. скорее всего в коде его инициализации идут тормоза. возможно там есть какие-то вычисления.

@Wlad в этом даже и приколдес, что в коде фрагмента кроме надувания макета ничего не происходит. Заметил что некоторые виджеты от Material Design грузят макет, в общем буду разбираться
